# Elasticsearch aggregation speed

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index split over 3 nodes, 9 shards, 2 replicas. The index contains ~200 million documents. What am I trying to do is to aggregate the most used other fields with a certain field value.

I am trying to get most used other field values with united states as country. The weird issue I am facing is that, let's say united states has 10 million documents under it the aggregation is taking about a minute to finish, and another country let's say France has 1 million documents under it, the aggregation is also taking about 1 minute to finish. So I am asking myself what am I doing wrong, or how does elasticsearch do the aggregation.

Here's my query

```
{
 "query" : {
    "bool": {
       "must": {
          "match": {
              "country": "united states"
          }
       }
     }
},
"size": 0,
"aggs" : {
    "organization" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "organization",
            "order" : { "_count": "desc" },
            "size" : 1
        }
    },
    "city" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "city",
            "order" : { "_count": "desc" },
            "size" : 1
        }
    }
}
}
```

Threadpool while query is running, deleted stats with only 0 in them except for search

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool
elastic-2 management          1 0 0
elastic-2 search              3 0 0
elastic-3 management          1 0 0
elastic-3 search              0 0 0
elastic-1 management          1 0 0
elastic-1 search              6 0 0
```

Comment: Basically coordinating shard asks every shard to run the aggregation and then reduces the result and sends it back to you. Can you check the stats of your node, like your search queue length and all while this query is executingv?

Comment: @krrish I updated my question.